# how to use pythonping with exectutor

Tags: python-3.x, executor, pythonping

I'm trying to capture IMCP ping results using [pythonping](https://pypi.org/project/pythonping/) on my Raspberry PI.
The documentation says it needs to be ran as root (undesirable), or I can use [executor](https://pypi.org/project/executor/) to work around this and run as user Pi using the *executor.Communicator* function.

I cannot find a working example of how to do this.

My test code is simple

```
from executor import execute
from pythonping import ping

# get average of 10 pings to host
# gives permission error
#ping("1.1.1.1",size=40,count=10)

# test of executor: capture result to variable
c=execute("hostname",capture=True)
print(c)
```

Somehow I use executor to process the ping request as a wrapper to get around needing to be root.
I'd love for someone to show me a working example of how to do this.

*pythonping* is exactly what I want because I can tell it to give me the average of 10 pings to a host.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using the [icmplib](https://pypi.org/project/icmplib/) library instead because it fully manages the exchanges and the structure of ICMP packets.

```
from executor import execute
from icmplib import ping

host=ping("1.1.1.1", count=4, privileged=False)
print(host.avg_rtt)
```